# How validate textbox (double,float type)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, textbox, validation

I need validate textbox.
range 0.0-200.0
and work with ',' and with '.'
How do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the NumericUpDown control in the [Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).

[image: NumericUpDown control]

Don't try and reinvent the wheel with a textbox; using a control explicitly designed for this purpose is *much* more user-friendly. It's immediately obvious that they're expected to enter a number, they can easily change the current value using recognizable methods, and you're freed from having to write and test a bunch of custom validation code.

Comment: I have error @Error    3    The type 'toolkit:NumericUpDown' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.@  in Blend4 - work, in VS2010 not work.